# Is there any way to have a private property in a class that is available in the HTML template in Angular?

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-components

I'm making a few custom components that will be used in different parts of my project (possibly more than one project) and I wanted to have a few properties to render in the HTML template of those components, but also not be available as `public` for other components that might include the said component.

For example:

My generic component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    title:string='TITLE'; // public because otherwise the template can't use it
}
```

Other component that includes `MyComponent` in its template

```
@Component({
    selector: 'other-component',
    templateUrl: './other-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./other-component.component.scss'],
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(MyComponent) my:MyComponent;
    ...
    fun(){
        this.my.title = "other title"; // this is what I don't want to happen
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to avoid `OtherComponent` to be able to use `MyComponent.title`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to expose private properties on an Angular component to the component's HTML Template.

You might be able to expose that property as a read only property by supplying a get method, but not a set method:

```
private _title:string='TITLE'; 
get title(): {
   return this._title;
}
```

In your second component, this method should throw an error, because title is a read only property:

```
this.my.title = "other title";
```

You should be able to access the value if you wanted, like this:

```
console.log(this.my.title);
```

But, will not be settable.

The caveat here is that if you're not using a literal, instead an array or object, the object properties can be modified even without setting the main property.

```
private _myObject = {}; 
get myObject(): {
   return this._myObject;
}
```

Then this would work fine:

```
this.my.myObject.title = "other title";
```